# Understanding a step in a proof of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,n]}(1+\frac{x}{n})^ne^{-2x}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, measurable-functions

Why was this $\int_{[0,n]}(1+\frac{x}{n})^ne^{-2x}dx=\int_{[0,\infty)}(1+\frac{x}{n})^ne^{-2x}\chi_{[0,n]}dx$ written in the proof?

Does this is related to the measurability of the function $g_n(x)$?

I do not see how. Even so I think the answer is 'yes' because the remaining  hypotheses of DCT are mentioned in the proof.

See the hypotheses of the dominated convergence theorem are

- A sequence of measurable functions $f_n$
- $g\in L(\mu)$
- $|f_n|\le g$
- $f_n\to f$ pointwise

> [Calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,n]}(1+\frac{x}{n})^ne^{-2x}dx$ .](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2285916/calculate-lim-n-to-infty-int-0-n1-fracxnne-2xdx)
>
> $\int_{[0,n]}(1+\frac{x}{n})^ne^{-2x}dx=\int_{[0,\infty)}(1+\frac{x}{n})^ne^{-2x}\chi_{[0,n]}dx$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $g_n(x)=(1+\frac{x}{n})^ne^{-2x}\chi_{[0,n]}dx$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x\in[0,\infty) $.Then $g_n(x)\leq e^{-x}$ for each $x\in[0,\infty)$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. $\int_{[0,\infty)}e^{-x}dx$ exists. Moreover $g_n(x)$ converges to $g(x)=e^{-x}$ for each $x$. Then by Dominated Convergence theorem $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,n]}(1+\frac{x}{n})^ne^{-2x}dx=\int_{[0,\infty)}e^{-x}dx$.

Comment: In the hypothesis of the dominated convergence theorem, the domain of integration does not depend on $n$. That is why one must first make use of the function $\chi$ in order to replace $[0,n]$ with the suitable $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: the identity $\int_{[0,n]}(1+\frac{x}{n})^ne^{-2x}dx=\int_{[0,\infty)}(1+\frac{x}{n})^ne^{-2x}\chi_{[0,n]}dx$ is trivial, what you mean? Remember that, for some $f:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ the notation of Lebesgue integrals is defined as $\int_A f:=\int_{\Bbb R^n} f\chi_A$. Also note that $$\int_{[0,\infty)} f\chi_{[0,n]}=\int_{\Bbb R}f\chi_{[0,n]}$$

Comment: @Masacroso I know it's trivial. What I meant was  why to write the triviality in the proof? Which I think it is because of Suzet's comment above. Besides that, where in the proof is shown that $g_n$ is measurable? I think it's not proved

Comment: @g.a.l.l.e.t.a  $g_n$ is piecewise continuous, so it is Lebesgue measurable. You only need to know that $g_n(x)\le e^{-x}$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$, then you can apply the dominated convergence theorem